# Change color of Buttons and layouts in different activities and fragments from one activity

Tags: android, android-color

I want to change background color of toolbar, linearlayout and buttons placed in various fragments and activities from one activity. I tried by saving a value in sharedpreference for every color and changing color according to that value in every fragment and activity. But the result was that in fragment the color was different as the value in sharedpreference changed in the activity first and then fragment was called. So, is there a better way to change color of different buttons in different layouts of fragments and activities from one activity? Like maybe using localbroadcast or something?

```
public interface ColorInterface{
    void myAction(String value) ;
}
```

// in fragment

```
@Override
public void myAction(String value) {

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
        if (getActivity()!=null)
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
    }else{
        if(value.equals("1")){
            if (getActivity()!=null)
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.mantis));
        }else if(value.equals("2")){
            if (getActivity()!=null)
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.sandybrown));
        }else if(value.equals("3")){
            if (getActivity()!=null)
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.bostonblue));
        }else if(value.equals("4")){
            if (getActivity()!=null)
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
    }


}
```

// in activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private TabLayout tabs;    
    private SharedPref pref;    
    private ColorInterface listener ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        tabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pref = new SharedPref(HomeActivity.this);       

    bindWidgetsWithAnEvent(); 

        setupTabLayout();

        if (findViewById(R.id.frame) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            HomeFragment frag1 = new HomeFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, frag1).commit();

        }

        changeColor();


    } // onCreate ends

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent(){

        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }   

    private void setupTabLayout() {

        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.home_white),true);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.category_white),true);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.upload_white),true);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.listing_white),true);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.user_white),true);

        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(0);
        tab.select();
    }

    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition){
        switch (tabPosition){
            case 0 :
                HomeFragment frag1 = new HomeFragment();
                setListener(frag1);
                replaceFragment(frag1);
                break;
            case 1 :
                CategoryFragment frag2 = new CategoryFragment();
                replaceFragment(frag2);
                break;
            case 2 :
                AddProdFragment1 frag3 = new AddProdFragment1();
                replaceFragment(frag3);
                break;
            case 3 :
                MyProdFragment frag4 = new MyProdFragment();
                replaceFragment(frag4);
                break;
            case 4 :
                MyProfileFragment frag5 = new MyProfileFragment();
                replaceFragment(frag5);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void replaceFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        if(!currentFragment.getClass().equals(fragment.getClass()))
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private void updateMyLoc(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Utility.UPDATEMYLOC,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jObj.getString("ACK").equals("1")){
                                System.out.println("sammy_loc_updated");

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            System.out.println("sammy_JSONError "+e);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,getString(R.string.tooslow),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,getString(R.string.nointernet),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_AuthFailureError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ServerError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_NetworkError "+error);
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    System.out.println("sammy_ParseError "+error);
                }
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_id", pref.getString(Utility.USERID));
                params.put("lat", String.valueOf(GPSTracker.currLat));
                params.put("long", String.valueOf(GPSTracker.currLong));
                params.put("device_token_id", "1234567890");
                params.put("device_type", "android");


                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(HomeActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }

    public void setListener(ColorInterface listener){
        this.listener = listener ;
    }

    private void changeColor(){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pref.getString(Utility.COLOR))){
            tabs.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            listener.myAction("");
            pref.setString(Utility.COLOR, "1");
        }else{
            if(pref.getString(Utility.COLOR).equals("1")){
                tabs.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.mantis));
                listener.myAction("1");
                pref.setString(Utility.COLOR, "2");
            }else if(pref.getString(Utility.COLOR).equals("2")){
                tabs.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.sandybrown));
                listener.myAction("2");
                pref.setString(Utility.COLOR, "3");
            }else if(pref.getString(Utility.COLOR).equals("3")){
                tabs.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bostonblue));
                listener.myAction("3");
                pref.setString(Utility.COLOR, "4");
            }else if(pref.getString(Utility.COLOR).equals("4")){
                tabs.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                listener.myAction("4");
                pref.setString(Utility.COLOR, "1");
            }
        }

    }

}
```